# touch handling in a customView like drawerLayout

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio, touch, drawerlayout

i have a custom view like drawer layout that has two child . a gridView that swipping( like listview in drawerLayout) and a another child as content. like drawer layout i want if a touch detected and that is scrolling touch   handle it in custom layout (call onTouchEvent() ) but if touch is a click on gridView items  gridView handle it. so i ovveride iterceptTouchEvent() and use GestureDEtector to detect scrolling but thats not worked.

```
   @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    if(isScrolling) {
         isScrolling = false;
         onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
     return false;
}

  public class touchDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{


    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.d("*********","ONScroll");
        isScrolling = true;
        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it way to complicated the TouchListener is all you need:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int viewId = v.getId();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            switch (viewId) {
                case R.id.viewId1: {
                    ...
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.viewId2: {
                    ...
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            switch (viewId) {
                ...
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thereby you can handle a specific action for a specific view and if you want to know if the user is scrolling, just compare the MotionEvent's `getHistoricalX()` or `getHistoricalY()` with `getX()` or `getY()`  in the `ActionDown case` so you will know the difference between the original touch-point and the current touch-point

Comment: thank you but  if onInterceptTouchEvent return false OnTouch() method not called for touching on childs positions.

Comment: just attach the touchlistener to your Activity/Fragment